# Update column values by adding a prefix to each column dynamically

Tags: r, string, for-loop, concatenation

I have a for loop,where I create a data frame inside that.Because of that data frame will take different shape in each round.Sametime I create string vector in each round where length of the vector is equal to number of columns of the data frame. as a example in a random round,data frame is `merged_` and string vector is `out.names`

```
merged_ <-  data.frame(V8 = c(19, 19, 1, 4, 4, 4),
                 V9 = c("9P0480", "9P0480", "9P0480", "9P0480", "9P0480", "9P0480"),
                 V10 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0),
                 V11 = c(4580,4580,4580,4580,4580,4580))

out.names <- c("hello","hello2","hello3","hello4")
```

Now I need to update each column by add string value as a prefix. output like this

```
df_new <- data.frame(V8 = c("hello:19", "hello:19", "hello:1", "hello:4", "hello:4", "hello:4"),
V9 = c("hello2:9P0480", "hello2:9P0480", "hello2:9P0480", "hello2:9P0480", "hello2:9P0480", "hello2:9P0480"),
V10 = c("hello3:0","hello3:0","hello3:0","hello3:0","hello3:0","hello3:0"),
V11 = c("hello4:4580","hello4:4580","hello4:4580","hello4:4580","hello4:4580","hello4:4580"))

        V8            V9      V10         V11
1 hello:19 hello2:9P0480 hello3:0 hello4:4580
2 hello:19 hello2:9P0480 hello3:0 hello4:4580
3  hello:1 hello2:9P0480 hello3:0 hello4:4580
4  hello:4 hello2:9P0480 hello3:0 hello4:4580
5  hello:4 hello2:9P0480 hello3:0 hello4:4580
6  hello:4 hello2:9P0480 hello3:0 hello4:4580
```

what I tried so far is,trying to update each column using for loop.

```
for (col in 1:ncol(merged_)) {

    merged_[,col] <- paste0(out.names[col],":",merged_[,col])
  }
```

This is the error when I try above code

> Error in `[.data.table`(merged_, , col) :    j (the 2nd argument
>   inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'col' is not found.
>   Perhaps you intended DT[,..col] or DT[,col,with=FALSE]. This
>   difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.

Is this can be solved by using some Vectorization method,without using for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map` and `paste` values from `out.names` and `merged_` column-wise.

```
merged_[] <- Map(paste, out.names, merged_, sep = ":")
merged_

#        V8            V9      V10         V11
#1 hello:19 hello2:9P0480 hello3:0 hello4:4580
#2 hello:19 hello2:9P0480 hello3:0 hello4:4580
#3  hello:1 hello2:9P0480 hello3:0 hello4:4580
#4  hello:4 hello2:9P0480 hello3:0 hello4:4580
#5  hello:4 hello2:9P0480 hello3:0 hello4:4580
#6  hello:4 hello2:9P0480 hello3:0 hello4:4580
```

This is similar to `map2` in `purrr`.

```
merged_[] <- purrr::map2(out.names, merged_, paste, sep = ":")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map2_df` from `purrr` with `str_c`

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
map2(out.names, merged_, ~ str_c(.x, .y, sep=":") %>% 
       as.list) %>% 
       tibble(new = .) %>%
  unnest_wider(new)
```